# htaccess url rewrite http www and non-www to https www + https non-www to https www

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am looking for a set of rewrite rules that will do the following:

- http www and http non-www to https www
- https non-www to https www

You could also say i want all url's that aren't equal to https://www.somedomain.com, rewritten to https://www.somedomain.com.

I have seen a lot of answers, but i couldn't find a set of rewrite rules that matches the above and difficulty combining some of them to one solid set of rules that will accomplish the above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why was OP not asked "What have you tried" for this question?

Comment: What/Who is OP? It seemed useless to post the numerous solutions that didn't do the job, if this is what you mean by 'What have you tried'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this single rule for that in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?somedomain1\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.somedomain1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?somedomain2\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.somedomain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How would i extend this if i have 2 domains where i want this to work (www.somedomain1.com, www.somedomain2.com)? And shouldn't have your rewrite rule have https instead of http?

Comment: Thank you! Now i also see the browser 'problem'. Browser output a warning* the website isn't save and right after you click 'visit unsave website', it does the rewrite after that (https:/non-www to https://www). But at least it rewrites now correctly! * = SSL is valid for www.somedomain.com only

Comment: browser warning shows up because SSL certificate negotiation happens before `mod_rewrite` rules.

Comment: @anubhava - I have used same rule as you mentioned on our website but I am getting error on browser "This webpage has a redirect loop", I also wants to redirect all requests with or without www & http to https://www.domain.com. 
I'd really appreciate any kind of your help.

Comment: @NipunTyagi: You might be having some conflicting rule as rules posted in this answer are working if used independently. You can open a new question and post your .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?somedomain1\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.somedomain1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

It's working for me except `https://somedomain1.com` that isn't redirected to `https://www.somedomain1.com`