# Redirect all non-www, www, http:// requests to https://www. using .htaccess file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking for a set of rewrite rules that will redirect all requests to https://www.domain.com:

- www or without www to https://www.domain.com
- https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com

I've checked lot of answers but I couldn't any solution that works for me, I've used the rule that I had found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490487/htaccess-url-rewrite-http-www-and-non-www-to-https-www-https-non-www-to-https)

but I am getting error on my browser "This webpage has a redirect loop".

Here is my .htaccess file

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 
# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.
# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com
Options +FollowSymlinks
# Prevent Directoy listing 

Options -Indexes
# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:

# php_flag register_globals off
# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M
# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields

# php_value post_max_size 999M
# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields

# php_value max_execution_time 200
# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields

# php_value max_input_time 200
# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

Really,Thanks in advance for any kind of help

Comment: FYI: `non-www` and `http://domain` is same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your first rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Replace `example.com` with your actual domain name.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, But I am still getting same error on browser, you can check it https://www.victoria-road.com/

Comment: Actually it worked fine for me. Clear your browser cache or test in a new browser.

Comment: hi @anubhava have applied the rule and it is getting redirected to www.my-website.com but I am getting this error "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Comment: That means you have some other rule/code in conflict. Please open a new question with all the details and I will look into that.